# Bitcoin qt won't update

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization, connection

I installed Bitcoin Qt, and it began updating the blocks extremely slowly. After several hours, I restarted the program, thinking it might speed it up. Now, it appears completely stagnant; the icon in the bottom right is now two monitors and an X, rather than the previous icons which denoted the rate of the update.

How can I get it to update the blocks? I'm waiting on some transferred funds, and this is starting to be a real hassle.

Comment: That X means your client is not making a connection out.   Is your Windows firewall blocking it, or are you on a network which blocks outgoing connection attempts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot access my bitcoins because my wallet is still synchronising. What can I do to retrieve them?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/6056/5406), [I didn't receive a Bitcoin Payment. What does it mean when the Client is synchronizing?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2124/5406)

Answer (score 1):

It is going to be slow when you first install. I'd recommend downloading the bootstrap.dat file. If there is an X and two monitors, you're either not connected to the internet or something like your firewall are preventing you from updating it.