# Bitcoin wallet not syncing

Tags: wallet, synchronization

My bit coin wallet sync is stuck, if anything the blocks remaining is increasing.
It is not my computer or network because I have another wallet on a different hard drive and that wallet synced in a day, but the problem wallet has been syncing for many many days.

The bit coin I have bought has not yet appeared in my wallet, so what are my options? I cannot transfer the purchased bit coin  before it appears in my wallet.

Comment: This question lacks sufficient information to enable any decent answer. As the question is several months old the user probably has already resolved his issue and it is doubtful that the question will be provided. Voted to close.

Comment: lannot access my bitcoins because my wallet is still synchronising. What can I do to retrieve them?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/6056/5406)

Answer (score 0):

First, a bit information about the underlying OS, bitcoin client config & hardware would be nice. Are you using a virtual environment?

The delay / increased time on the sync problem is hardly to evaluate without this information.

How long is it stuck? How long have you been loading? How much GB have you already loaded?

First thing to check would be the connection, are you using UpnP or forwarded porting? How much bandwidth do you got? Is there a firewall in the way? Ports on switches/virtual environments?
If thats not the problem maybe IO is it. Right after that i would check if hte cpu is running hot.