# Wallet says “unsynchronised”, is that stopping me from seeing my bitcoins that I just received?

Tags: wallet, synchronization

I don't see the bitcoins I was supposed to receive today at 3PM and I tried to close the application to refresh it but it still hasn't arrived. I used GoldUX so that he could send my webmoney to my bitcoin wallet. I gave him the address that took it from my bitcoin application on my windows first.

So right now I'm seeing a wallet (unsynchronized) is this the reason why I cant see the money I was supposed to have received???

Comment: Related question: [Cannot access my bitcoins because my wallet is still synchronising. What can I do to retrieve them?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/6056/cannot-access-my-bitcoins-because-my-wallet-is-still-synchronising-what-can-i-d)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely the case. If your wallet is not synchronized, that means that it does not yet have a record of all transactions. Since synchronization happens in the order that blocks (and thus transactions) occurs, your later transactions will not show up until the synchronization reaches that point, which could take a while...

If you want to confirm that your coins went through without having to synchronize your wallet, you have at least two options:

*Web-based Wallets* such as *BlockChain.info* are connected to a backend service that is constantly synchronized. With blockchain.info, you can search for the public address to which your coins were sent without having to go through any signup process. This is probably your easiest option.

*Electrum* (http://electrum.org/) is a wallet that connects to servers that are already synchronized and thus will give you immediate results as well.

Also, there is a vague possibility, that this issues is caused by something other than the synchronization, so, if the options above don't work, please update the question with more details.

Comment: Alright thank you for that info but do you know why is it taking so long to syncronize? It's at 88 weeks o.o

Comment: A number of factors can influence this including your network speed and your computer's processing power. It could also be a random bug. I'd check out http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=taking+so+long as this seems to be a common problem.

Comment: Also, it could be majorly helpful to the community if you could vote up useful answers and/or set answers as chosen if they fully address your question.

Comment: Also i noticed my gigabytes on my computer went down...dramatically is the bitcoin application causing that???

Comment: According to http://blockchain.info/charts/blocks-size, the block chain is almost 10GB in size. So, yes.

Comment: Help, i was running bitcoin and i saw this error message popup saying...https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/4311082/448597/8b3c34ae-b250-11e2-8589-350820a68082.jpg what could be causing this and how can i fix it?

Comment: At this point, you probably want to start another question thread as this is off topic. (Also, this extends beyond my expertise.)