# Bitcoin Core V 0.10.0: Is there a way to force send when not synchronized?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, synchronization

My Bitcoin Core is not yet synchronized, but I already attempted sending a transaction, so now it is 'conflicted'.
I can see this conflicted transaction is not being propagated.
Is there a way to force the sending of that transaction?
I know for sure that whatever input it will use, that transaction will be valid.

Thanks!

Comment: related: [Cannot access my bitcoins because my wallet is still synchronising. What can I do to spend them immediately?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/6056/5406)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not force a transaction.

Your bitcoin core wallet will only trust receiving and sending transactions once you are synchronised. Your wallet is currently doing something similar to time travelling. It is synchronising all transaction from the genenis block to the current block.

The blockchain is a numerical sequence of the proof of existance of every transaction recorded on Bitcoins world wide ledger. Your Tx will be propagated as soon as you have downloaded this chain of truth.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_chain