# Bitcoin Core Network Configuration

Tags: bitcoin-core, network, payment

I am having difficulty loading the full node for my new Bitcoin Core wallet. I use a Mac and share a modem with my apartment complex. I believe a manual network configuration is out of the cards for me. My node stopped loading with 31 weeks to go and I am still waiting to receive my first payment.

Is there another electronic wallet that does not require so much configuration? Also, is it possible to take my key for the expected payment and use it in another electronic wallet?

in over my head.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot access my bitcoins because my wallet is still synchronising. What can I do to spend them immediately?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/6056/5406)

Comment: If it actually stopped, and will not make progress even if you leave the application open for more than half an hour or so, the database state is likely corrupted. You can start the program with the -reindex command line flag, or delete the chainstate directory to recover from that. Do not delete wallet.dat (and make a backup of that file first).

Answer (score 1):

Add some nodes to help speed it up if it freezes here are a few.

First open bitcoin.conf with notepad or notepad++

Type "addnode " and the ip

Example addnode=66.228.49.201

You can add as many as you feel you will need save it then restart your client and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin Core doesn't require much configuration.

The instructions for running it on a Mac are located at https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#mac-os-x-instructions

The reason you can't get a payment yet is because it's still downloading the blockchain. Until the client downloads the block that contains your transaction, it doesn't know it exists.

Regarding it freezing with 31 weeks to go, I would advise letting it continue to run, some blocks take longer then others to download.

Keep an eye on the number of blocks it's on (found by hovering over the sync icon in the lower right of the program. It's probably going up very slowly.

Comment: I already viewed those instructions. The blockchain will not download unless I configure the modem. The modem is my apartment complex's so configuring is not possible. I would like to use another wallet that doesn't require this configuration. Any recommendations? Would it be possible to give another address to the payer since my transaction has not been completed?

Comment: No configuration is needed on the modem. The blockchain downloads on the outbound ports and you know this is correct because otherwise you would be at 4 years, not 31 weeks. The transaction is done, the coins are in that wallet now. You just have to wait.

Comment: I checked on whether my port was open on https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#enabling-connections and no luck. I was downloading just fine until 2 days ago when it stopped on 31 weeks. No synchronization has taken place since. Is there something I can do outside of manually adjusting a modem?

Comment: The download has simply stopped and will not start up again. The app shows synchronizing with network, but nothing is happening. Also, I am unable to locate the wallet.dat in my applications support folder. There is no Bitcoin folder in this folder. I have searched all my files and am unable to locate a wallet.dat.