# Coins not yet refllecting in wallet

Tags: e-wallet

i transferred coins to my wallet, but the wallet hasn't finished syncing with the network as yet, so the coins have not reflected. Is this something i need to be concerned about? Do i just wait for it to finish and then see if they appear? I did use the address the wallet gave me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you sent the amount to the correct address you have nothing to worry about. This is expected for a wallet that has to download and verify the whole blockchain. Other wallets use [SPV](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Scalability#Simplified_payment_verification) that only verifies transactions for your addresses and thus they do not have to download the whole blockchain. Examples of SPV wallets for the desktop are [Multibit](https://multibit.org/) and [Electrum](https://electrum.org).

After syncing you will see the balance reflected but you could also immediately check if the coins arrived to your address correctly with a block explorer. E.g. go to [Blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/) or [BlockExplorer](https://blockexplorer.com/) and search for your address: you will see the amount on that address, the number of confirmations, etc.

Comment: Also check [this](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/6056/cannot-access-my-bitcoins-because-my-wallet-is-still-synchronising-what-can-i-d) if you want to use your coins right now.