# How can I use bitcoins on deposit?

Tags: wallet

I had received bitcoins before my wallet was fully synchronized and it took several days for it to finish the process, so I decided to deposit the bitcoins in another wallet. Now I can see they are "on deposit", but they do not show up in my other wallet. How can I move them to my wallet or use them?
Thank you!

Comment: related: [Cannot access my bitcoins because my wallet is still synchronising. What can I do to spend them immediately?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/6056/5406)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to send newly received Bitcoins from a wallet that is not yet synchronized you have two choices:

1. Wait until your incoming Bitcoin transaction has synced. Your wallet cannot send Bitcoins that it cannot yet determine it has received (because it has not yet synced to the block height were you received the BTC)
2. Import the keys of your receiving address or HD wallet into a wallet that has fully synced the blockchain or a light/SPV wallet

Please understand that you own any Bitcoin for which you control the private keys and that Bitcoin can be used with any wallet. However just because you own Bitcoin does not mean that you can spend it from a wallet that is not yet synchronized. When a wallet is not synchronized at least up to the point where an address you control has received the Bitcoin you are looking for, your wallet has no way to verify your ownership of that BTC.

Answer (score -1):

I have noticed myself that does take some time for everything to synchronize but once it does it'll be there for you