# Sent Bitcoin to Bitcoin Core Wallet before it finished "syncing with network"

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization

So I bought some bitcoins and sent it to my Bitcoin core wallet before it finished syncing with network, will the transactions come through once it finishing syncing or have I lost them?

Comment: related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/6056/5406

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes everything will be normal, the bitcoin will reach your wallet once it downloaded the block your transactions was included in :).
Just wait patiently .

Comment: Praise the lord! was so worried :')