# How do I transfer btc from Core that never finishes syncho to another wallet?

Tags: transactions, synchronization

My Core finished sychro after 4 months, the transaction was visible finally (then I moved all data from one file in the computer to another) and Core started synchro again with 3 yrs remaining. It shows no transactions now.

How do I get the funds from there to another wallet, I have the receiveing address from BTC.
?

Comment: related: [Cannot access my bitcoins because my wallet is still synchronising. What can I do to spend them immediately?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/6056/5406)

Answer (score 0):

Even though your wallet is still syncing you can use the debug console or bitcoin-cli along with `dumpprivkey` to get the private key of one of your wallet addresses. You can then import the key to an SPV wallet.