# Transfer incoming funds from Bitcoin Core to another wallet before blockchain sync is completed

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization, private-key-export

This is my situation:

I have a Bitcoin-QT wallet on my Mac (Qt version 4.7.4.- yes I know its very old). only recently I've been working out how to operate and exchange bitcoins. well to cut a long story short i went to bitbargain.co.uk and bought an mbtc, managed to completed the transaction with relative ease and saw the bitcoin in my Bitbargain.co.uk account.

I then decided to transfer this purchase to my wallet on my Mac and did so but entering a received address on the bitbargain account page. I waited and waited and have not seen the bitcoin come through on my Bitcoin-qt wallet.

It looks like there is a lot of syncing to do! only 45.65% complete, needs to catch up around 1720 days, this I estimate will be around 2 months if not more? that is if it actually completes?

My question is this, is there a way to move this purchase to another wallet I have, without having to let this wallet sync 100%? as the time frame required is very uncertain?

Can i transfer a bitcoin from bitcoin-qt to another wallet even though it is not showing up in my wallet becuase it is 1720 days out of sync?

Thanks for the help with this guys!

Best
FT

Comment: Closely related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/6056/5406

Answer (score 2):

After watching more than 100 videos, because I couldn't find a solution here, I was able to regain access to my BTC successfully from my old QT wallet without synchronizing the 310GB of blocks.  The solution is to import the private key of your old bitcoin-QT into a new Electrum wallet (this happens without fee):

1. Install from Electrum.org and create a new Electrum wallet  choosing the option "Import Bitcoin address or private keys"
2. Install from Bitcoin.org and create a new Bitcoin-Core wallet.
3. If Bitcoin Core is already open, stop the main sync in the lower right corner.
4. Turn off Bitcoin Core. Go to `C:\User\yourname\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin\wallets\your new wallet\wallet.dat`
5. Obviously, this new Bitcoin Core wallet was never used, so delete the `wallet.dat` file
6. Paste your  `old-wallet.dat` file (the one you backed up years ago from your bitcoin QT), rename the pasted `old-wallet.dat` to `wallet.dat`
7. Open Bitcoin Core again --> hide --> stop synchronization (bottom right) --> Window --> Console --> Type below the command `dumpprivkey` and the old public address --> Enter.
8. When your private key appears, copy it. (In my case it didn't ask for my old passphrase.) Now go to your new Electrum wallet and paste the private key in the "Import Bitcoin address" box -> Next.
   (do it in private and without cell phone cameras).
9. Now enter a new password twice and accept the wallet encryption.
10. Ready, now you have access to your BTC (with the same old public address) to spend or send them wherever you want,   but since your private key is exposed, I recommend you send them as soon as possible to a new destination that is safer (even if you have to pay a fee this time).

Comment: Hi AndreH, welcome to Stackexchange, thank you for taking the time to share your research! Am I understanding right that these are the instructions for Windows?