# Can I import my wallet while my btc core is syncing

Tags: bitcoin-core, electrum, wallet-import

I'm upgrading my btc core to v0.18.1. I'd like to export my wallet to electrum. Is it possible while syncing? How?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/6056/5406

Answer (score 1):

[Like this?](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transferring_coins_from_Bitcoin-Qt_to_Electrum)

> This guide is intended for users of Bitcoin-Qt who do not want to wait for their wallet to be synchronized with the network, which may take many hours or days depending on the hardware spec. The guide teaches users how to transfer their coins to Electrum bitcoin wallet, which has lower security but a faster startup time.

To answer your question, yes you can.  Syncing the blockchain has nothing to do with your private keys.  Electrum has a list of blockchain servers to use your keys with immediately.

Comment: I did that with all the receiving addresses I had on my btc qt wallet but my account doesn't match. I'm missing some btc. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is there any way to import the whole wallet? Doesn't seem like it would make a difference but I don't know why I'm missing some btc from my account.

Comment: You can dump your Master HD key.  Go to the same console and type `dumpwallet (filename)` then get the xprv key at the top of the file.

Comment: I updated the answer above.

Comment: @tgunnoe Downvoted. Bitcoin Core uses a hardened derivation to derive keys from master private key. From the account level, Electrum uses a non-hardened derivation. So the master private keys are not interchangeable between Bitcoin Core and Electrum. What can be done is dumping each key individually and then importing each key in Electrum.

Comment: Alright, thanks. edited answer from above. New information for me