# How to transfer from unsync'd Bitcoin core wallet to Electrum?

Tags: bitcoin-core, electrum, synchronization, wallet-recovery

I would like to transfer my btc wallet to an electrum wallet. Syncing is taking to long.

Comment: related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/6056/5406

Answer (score 1):

Follow [this guide.](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transferring_coins_from_Bitcoin-Qt_to_Electrum)

Summary:

- Download Electrum and verify the signature to prove it was not modified in transit. Create a new Standard Wallet and choose "Create a new seed". Electrum will give you a seed phrase which you should write down on paper.
- If using Bitcoin-Qt, click Window -> Console.
- If your wallet is encrypted, use this command to decrypt it for 5 minutes (300 seconds):

```
walletpassphrase your-wallet-passphrase 300
```

If addresses with balance are known:

- Use the dumpprivkey command to get the private key. Repeat for as many bitcoin addresses as have money in them.

```
dumpprivkey <your bitcoin address>
```

If addresses with balance are not known:

- Use the dumpwallet command to get all private keys from the wallet.

```
dumpwallet path/to/exported-wallet.txt
```

- In the Electrum window, click Wallet -> Private Keys -> Sweep. Paste the private keys from Bitcoin-Qt here. Check the resulting transaction is okay and click Broadcast to sweep from the addresses in Bitcoin Core to the Electrum wallet.

  - If the address generated from the private key is wrong, then on the Sweep Private keys dialog box in Electrum click the Info box in the upper-right. It will give instructions for prefixing your private key so that the correct address is generated. For example if your address starts with 3 then use `p2wpkh-p2sh:[your-private-key]`.

**Warning: Make sure the Electrum wallet is not a watch-only wallet. The Electrum window title bar should not say [watching-only].**

Comment: Worth noting that "sweeping" cost mining fees, it's actually transferring all the coins to the newly created Electrum wallet.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the syncing using the icons in the bottom right and send your coins using the send tab.