# btc qt walletdump

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, electrum, synchronization

I'd like to dump my entire btc qt wallet, while syncing, into an electrum wallet.

I don't want to do it receiving address by receiving address.

I already emptied out all my receiving addresses but there are still some left on the wallet.

I know that sounds wrong but it is true.

Maybe someone could explain otherwise.

I've tried dumping wallet in the debug console but am having problems with that too.

I have posted on this forum about this problem for awhile to no avail.

Is there another platform that could assist me or help?

Comment: Have you tried the dumpwallet command in Bitcoin QT's command line? This command should dump both External and Internal private keys.

Comment: I try but red letters pop up " .....(code-1)." Do you know anything about that? Is there a website that explains the debug console commands and responses?

Comment: How do you know there are still funds left on the bitcoin-core wallet? Did you know the exact amount sent to that wallet (and now the amount recovered to electrum is obviously less than that), or is it just that bitcoin-core is still showing some funds are left (while syncing)?

Comment: I know the exact amount in my btc qt. Emptied receiving addresses to electrum wallet. Does not equal original btc qt wallet amount. Do you have any suggestions? Dumpwallet is the only thing I can come up with. And I'm having problems with that. Do you know of a more advanced platform online I can bring this problem to or a physical location that trouble shoots this stuff?

Comment: @requim This is about the most advanced platform to ask your questions to. To use the command "dumpwallet" you need to specify the location+name you want to dump the file to. "dumpwallet Path/To/OutputFile.txt" Keep in mind you first need to unlock your wallet. Please see [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/92636/100415)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do you transfer your Bitcoin core wallet while syncing?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/92634/how-do-you-transfer-your-bitcoin-core-wallet-while-syncing)

Comment: Not really. I've seen that link/answer before. I know how to unlock my wallet using the debug console. I am having problems dumping my wallet. I don't know if it's because the path is wrong or the wallet is synching or maybe another error. When I try to dumpwallet I get red text in the debug console, (code-1). There is a lot more text but it won't all fit in this section. Do you know of a link or site that can explain the responses of the debug console?

Comment: @requim have you tried using the `listunspent` command? If your node isn’t fully synced it may not be useful, but there is a chance if may help you figure out which UTXOs haven’t been transferred yet.

Comment: What are the parameters of using the listunspent command in the debug console. Chytrik. Nothing is happening. Not even red letter errors. Does anyone know where I can just bring my laptop to solve this problem? This has been going on for months now. The Bitcoin community really needs to open up to this. Troubleshooting like this is a real debacle.

Comment: I've gone to some btc Meetups for assistance but these people are mostly just looking for yield. I think there is a real opportunity for someone to start a business like Geek Squad or something like that.

Comment: Ok I put listunspent in debug console and brackets, [ ], show up with nothing in between.