# listaddressgroupings or dumpwallet? I need to dump private keys from Bitcoin-QT

Tags: bitcoin-core, electrum, private-key-export

I have a Bitcoin-QT wallet and the client is more than a year out of sycn. It would take years and massive amount of data to get it synced so, this is out of the question.

My plan was to move my coins to Electrum using swipe private keys.

**Here is where it gets confusing.**

If I run `listaddressgroupings`

I get few addresses, address "A1" has 0 balance, "A2" has my BTC.

If I use `dumpwallet` I get a list of 100 addresses

If I run `listreceivedbyaddress` I get one address, same as "A1" but it shows the same amount as "A2".

Question: What address should I use to get the private keys for swiping to Electrum?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transfer from unsync'd Bitcoin core wallet to Electrum?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/92634/how-do-you-transfer-your-bitcoin-core-wallet-while-syncing)