# Synchronising with network

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, synchronization

I'm completely new to Bitcoin but finding it all very interesting so far! My Bitcoin-qt wallet has been synchronising for literally days now (2 days actually) but it is getting closer, on 91% now. My question is, if I was to buy a Bitcoin from MtGox or somewhere, would I have to wait for the synchronisation to complete before I could see my coins? My transfer would have to be confirmed on the block chain through mining and would be the latest on the chain meaning I'd have to wait until it came through right? Would you wait it out?

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [I didn't receive a Bitcoin Payment. What does it mean when the Client is synchronizing?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2124/5406)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to purchase bitcoin and send it to an address in your wallet, then yes, **you would have to wait until your wallet synchronized in order to spend the bitcoins**.

However, in the meantime, **consider spending it directly from your exchange account**, especially if you're going to buy bitcoin and spend it right away.

Alternatively, **consider using an online wallet**. I recommend [Blockchain.info](http://Blockchain.info) or [InstaWallet](http://instawallet.org).