# How long does it take to download blockchain

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, synchronization

My question is how long does it take on average to download whole blockchain and set-up new wallet with standard Bitcoin-QT client.

Comment: Look on internet, there are plenty of sites discussing this. I think there are already several question on this stackexhange too. PS. usually one day, depending on your BUS and CPU speed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How long should synchronizing your wallet for the first time take?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/11029/how-long-should-synchronizing-your-wallet-for-the-first-time-take)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your bandwidth and (to a lesser extent) your power of your CPU, because each block requires verification. You can see the latest size at [here](https://blockchain.info/charts/blocks-size). Currently it is 10.8GB or so.

One option to speed up the download is to download a bootstrap.dat. The Bitcoin client will look for a "bootstrap.dat" file to pre-seed blocks. You can download on version of bootstrap.dat at [bitcoincharts.com](http://eu2.bitcoincharts.com/blockchain/). In most cases this will be faster, than the under-resourced bitcoin network.

Alternatively, if you run linux try this batch script:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ -z "$1" ] && echo "Usage: input=coinname" && exit 1
coin="$1"

while sleep 1; do
blk="$(eval "$coin getblockcount")"
h="$(eval "$coin getblockhash $blk")"    
coin_t="$(eval "$coin getblock $h" | grep '"time"' | awk '{print $3}' | sed -e 's/,//g')"

d="$[$(date +%s) - $coin_t]"; dm="$[$d / 60]"; dh="$[$dm / 60 ]"; dd="$[$dh / 24 ]"
echo "Difference from main chain $d s. or $dm m.  or $dh h.  or $dd d."

if [ -z "$first_t" ];then
        first_t="$d"
        start_watch_time="$(date +%s)"
else
        difference=$[$first_t - $d]
        speed="$(echo "$difference / $[$(date +%s) - $start_watch_time ]" | bc -l)" 
        remain_seconds="$(echo "$d / $speed" | bc -l)" 
        remain_minutes="$(echo "$remain_seconds / 60" | bc -l)"
        remain_hours="$(echo "$remain_minutes / 60" | bc -l)"
        remain_days="$(echo "$remain_hours / 24" | bc -l)"
        # eval "$coin getinfo"
        echo -n "Approximate Time Remaining: $remain_seconds seconds to complete  sync."
        echo "[m: $remain_minutes; h: $remain_hours; d: $remain_days ]"
fi    
[ "$LAST_BLK" == "$blk" ] && echo "Alarm! Stuck on block # $blk!"
LAST_BLK="$blk"
done
```

Save it to "coin_get_diff.sh" and run:

```
$ bash coin_get_diff.sh bitcoind
```

Example output:

```
...
....
Difference from main chain 2528577 s. or 42142 m.  or 702 h.  or 29 d.
Approximate Time Remaining: 2186.83957899106610047826 seconds to complete  sync.[m: 36.44732631651776834130; h: .60745543860862947235; d: .02531064327535956134 ]
Difference from main chain 2526232 s. or 42103 m.  or 701 h.  or 29 d.
Approximate Time Remaining: 2184.21035499949140474011 seconds to complete  sync.[m: 36.40350591665819007900; h: .60672509861096983465; d: .02528021244212374311 ]
Difference from main chain 2524021 s. or 42067 m.  or 701 h.  or 29 d.
Approximate Time Remaining: 2205.15551284291455530316 seconds to complete  sync.[m: 36.75259188071524258838; h: .61254319801192070980; d: .02552263325049669624 ]
...
..
```