# bitcoind just hangs (no output at all)

Tags: bitcoind

I do realize that in the early stages bitcoin has to download a lot ([How long does it take to download the blockchain?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9816/how-long-does-it-take-to-download-the-blockchain-its-been-over-a-day-and-still)), however, I assume this is like `wget` or `rsync` where it displays the progress. Right now, when I issue the command `bitcoind`, it just hangs and outputs nothing. Could this be due to closed ports? Is it sufficient that I opened ports on my Ubuntu router, or must I forward those ports? Alternatively, is there a command line parameter I have to issue to get the output of bitcoind?

Answer (score 6):

No output is normal, it's meant to be run as a daemon. If you want to see progress however, try `bitcoind -printtoconsole` or `tail -f ~/.bitcoin/debug.log`.

Answer (score 4):

You should be using something like so to run bitcoind as a daemon

```
bitcoind -daemon
```

And then, you can check on it like so:

```
bitcoind getinfo
```

Comment: All I get is "error: couldn't connect to server"

Comment: Scratch that, it is magically working now. I guess it needed time...

Comment: @puk yea, I forgot about that. Sometimes it can take a minute or two to warm up

Comment: Newer builds use `bitcoin-cli` to connect to the daemon rather than commands with `bitcoind`. You can pass `-rpcwait` to this to stop calls failing when the daemon is still checking it's files and starting up.