# interacting with bitcoin over docker

Tags: bitcoin-core

I've created a docker container of an ubuntu machine, loaded it up with all the dependencies specified in the unix build doc and then built bitcoin and run it with the following command:

```
./src/bitcoind
```

after that there's no output or evidence that anything is happening, the terminal is just hanging there, clearly something is going on- but I don't know/can't see what it is.

how can I examine the activity? For instance, see the coins that are being generated in my wallet, etc.

I've tried [this proposed solution](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/18033/what-does-getinfo-output-mean), i.e. to write

```
bitcoind getinfo
```

but I got the error

```
Error: There is no RPC client functionality in bitcoind anymore. Use the bitcoin-cli utility instead.
```

---

**Regarding** `-regtest`

I tried with:

```
./src/bitcoin-cli -regtest &
```

and I got the error:

```
too few parameters (need at least command)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the terminal is just hanging there

Yes, if you want it to run in the background, you need to run with the `-daemon` flag.

> how can I examine the activity?

You can look at the `debug.log` file (in the [datadir](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/4007/208)), or you can run with the `-printtoconsole` flag. You can increase the verbosity using the `-debug` flag (or specify a specific category, for example `-debug=mempool`; to see the various debug categories and more, use `-help`).

> For instance, see the coins that are being generated in my wallet, etc.

The built-in miner was [removed in Bitcoin Core v0.13.0](https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.13.0#removal-of-internal-miner), as it was not even useful for testing purposes anymore. If you want coins, you'll need to either buy them, get someone to send you some, or run a mining setup (which at the time of writing almost certainly requires custom ASIC hardware).

> I've tried this proposed solution, i.e. to write
>
> > bitcoind getinfo

You need to use `bitcoin-cli` now to communicate with `bitcoind` (since a few years ago...). The `getinfo` command still works but is deprecated. More specific information can be obtained using the RPC calls:

- `getblockchaininfo`
- `getpeerinfo`
- `getnetworkinfo`
- `getwalletinfo`
- `gettxoutsetinfo`
- `getaddednodeinfo`
- `getmempoolinfo`

Comment: I think I sort of got what I was looking for with this one `./src/bitcoin-cli getinfo`, but actually I don't want to connect to the real bitcoin network, I want to start over from scratch, create my own personal testnet, do you know how to do this?

Comment: so then does that mean that I can't use bitcoin core for creating a testnet, since it can't mine?

Comment: how to get around this error `error: Could not locate RPC credentials. No authentication cookie could be found, and no rpcpassword is set in the configuration file (/root/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf)`

Comment: That means `bitcoind` is not running (or perhaps you're running it with `-testnet` or `-regtest` but not passing that same argument to `bitcoin-cli`?).

Comment: And you can always run external mining software (like bfgminer) to construct blocks; it's much faster than any code we're able to maintain in Core. If it's just for a local testnet (-regtest mode), you can use the built-in `generate` RPC still (but only for chains where the difficulty is trivially low).

Comment: ah, ok. thank you for these insights. do you know what steps I would need to take to generate a fresh testnet from scratch? what I'd like to do eventually is have my own version of a real fork that I can make changes to- but I guess I might start by just creating my own version of bitcoin on a small network with some of my own machines

Comment: I would suggest to start in `-regtest` mode. You'll get an empty chain with only a genesis block, and no default connections anywhere. You can then use -connect to add nodes to your network and experiment. If you're further ahead, modify chainparams.cpp to add a definition for your own network and logic to select it.

Comment: do you know what I should do to chainparams.cpp  to define my own network?

Comment: That's far too much to explain in comments of an answer here. I suggest you study the source code and experiment with regtest first.

Comment: I've tried to start with 'regtest' and I got again that rpc error, and something about not enough arguments, do you know some resource I could look at about this?

Comment: https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#regtest-mode

Comment: I read that and tried those examples but it's what generated that not enough arguments error- also sometimes it refers to 'bitcoind' and sometimes 'cli', what about this one: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/28107/bitcoin-is-not-connected-in-regtest-mode

Comment: Can you open a new question with the exact commands you're running and error messages you get?

Comment: yes, sure I'll do that

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/52857/trouble-with-bitcoin-cli-regtest