# I am new and I did not get bitcoins

Tags: synchronization, buy-bitcoins

I am new to Bitcoin. So, I downloaded the Windows Bitcoins software from the official website and used the "request bitcoins" option to request bitcoins from my exchanger.

My exchanger charged me $20 and told me he will send me bitcoins corresponding to $20. But even after 18-20 hours I didn't receive any bitcoins.

Additionally, the Bitcoin software is showing `synchronizing with network : x years xx weeks` remaining.

What should I do? Should I wait for the synchronizing to complete or file a complaint against exchanger?

Comment: This question seems to come up a lot. Do we, or should we, have a "canonical duplicate"?

Comment: I think your answer here would qualify. I'll have a look around and see what other candidates there are, then I'll post to meta.

Comment: possible duplicate: [I didn't receive a Bitcoin Payment. What does it mean when the Client is synchronizing?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2124/5406)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, wait for it to finish synchronizing. You will not see your coins until it finishes.

(Note that the time shown is not the estimated time until completion; it represents the age of the old transactions currently being downloaded. Depending on the speed of your computer and internet connection, you can expect it to finish in a few hours to a few days.)

In the meantime, you can enter your address in a "block explorer" site like http://blockchain.info to check whether the seller made the transaction as agreed. (This is safe; your address alone cannot be used to steal your coins.)

If you don't want to download the entire block chain, you can use a different client such as Multibit, but you will have to import your wallet.dat from Bitcoin Core into your new client software. Its documentation should explain how to do that.