# Slow synchronisation bitcoin-qt - bread wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization, breadwallet

I have used bitcoin-qt for a while, but I have read now there is bread wallet for iOS more secure than any OS X wallet, is this true ?

I didn't update it for a while and now it is like 60+weeks behind and it will take a year or so to get it up to date... I made bitcoin transfer to someone on last thursday (4 days ago), it still does not show up, I can see in my log it as payment but with 0/6 confirmations (so I quess I need to update my wallet before transaction going out?)

I installed bread wallet to my iPhone, however I don't know how I can move my bitcoin qt data to it ? Breadwallet asks for recovery code OR new wallet, how I can synch wallets ?

Comment: related: [I didn't receive a Bitcoin Payment. What does it mean when the Client is synchronizing?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2124/5406)

Comment: Any faster / more secure wallet around there ? I have read good things from bread wallet but I don't know how to move my stuff from qt to it :/

Comment: The "one year" in "will take one year" refers to the amount of blockchain data that you still need to synchronize, not the time that it will take to synchronize.

Answer (score -2):

You need to import your bitcoin-qt private key(s) into breadwallet.