# "Invalid address" when trying solo mine with bfgminer

Tags: bitcoin-core, bfgminer

I am trying to mine solo.

I have installed `BitCoin Core` on my Windows box, set up incoming connections

[image]

and wrote in config file `<BitCoinStore>/bitcoin.conf`

```
server=1
rpcuser=myusername
rpcpassword=mypassword
```

Then on Linux box I ran

```
bfgminer -o http://mywindowsaddress:8333 -u myusername -p mypassword --generate-to myincomingaddress
```

and got

```
[2020-11-13 12:23:23] bfgminer: --generate-to: Invalid address
```

Why? What is invalid?

Should I run `bitcoind` instead of thus GUI on Windows?

Comment: Did you replace "myincomingaddress" with your actual address?

Comment: Yes, I took this address from BitcoinCore in section "receive". But I noticed, that it looks different than in examples: all characters are lowercase in mine, while in examples uppercase and lowercase mixed.

Comment: @Dims https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/98499/