# Bitcoin core Recent Transactions seems Empty

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, blockchain.info, bitcoin-core-development, bitcoin-qt-setup

I have setup bitcoin core 0.20.1.
Everything is set up correctly, I made a transaction on main net - but it is not showing under recent transactions. Though transaction is confirmed on blockchain.

Also when I am running command getblockinfo, block and header not matched.

Kindly give me a direction in to it.

Comment: Did you just start using Bitcoin Core? Has it finished the initial synchronization? Possibly related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2124/5406

Comment: Sounds like you are still syncing. Run command getblockcount to see what blockheight your node is at.