How to get the balance before downloading whole blockchain in bitcoin-core
i didn't work with bitcoin-core before and after i run the app i generate an address and send some bitcoin to it, now the bitcoin-core says i should download the whole blockchain before giving you your balance and as you know it's not a small data (about 450GB). is it possible to get the private key of the address or any way to get out the bitcoins without downloading the whole blockchain? i tried dumpprivkey and it returned Only legacy wallets are supported by this command (code -4). my address is a bc1 type of address.

Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/6056/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2124/5406

Does this answer your question? How do I get the private key of an address in descriptor wallets? How to dumpprivkey?
